# Unity Prefab icons displayed wrong

Tags: unity, prefabs

Occasionally the prefab icons are displayed wrong.
It either displays another icons preview, lets say "Side_Panel_4" displays "Side_Panel_1" icon. Or like the example bellow it goes completely white.

If I change the name of the prefab or make a change inside it, then the prefab icon sometimes gets fixed.
But I am no longer able to use that same name or the exact same configuration for a prefab once it bugs out like this.
If I use the same name then the icon will always be that white panel.

It would be nice if I can clear unity cache so that the name of the bugged prefab is forgotten, but I am unable to find where or how to do that.

What I tried without any success:

- Edit => Preferences => GI Cache => Clean cache
- In ForwardRenderer set masks to "Everything"
- Select prefab => Reimport
- Restarted Unity
- Refresh Project window

Using Unity Unity 2021.1.4f1 (64-bit)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried deleting their .meta file ?

Comment: That is a good idea, though I was hoping for a solution that would work on everything at once. It would get quite tedious to constantly having to delete each files metadata every time a prefab bugs out.